# How to cancel pending API calls in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, api, http, angular-http

I have a Search box and for every letter a user types I have 4 API calls being made.
and if user types a long word , many API calls goes in pending state. with every new letter which user types how do i check and cancel if previous call is in pending state .

```
FController.prototype.typeAheadSearch = function (query) {
    var this_ = this;
    var dfd = this.$q.defer();
    this.$q.all([this.TypeAheadFactory.API.A(query),
                 this.TypeAheadFactory.API.B(query),
                 this.TypeAheadFactory.API.C(query),
                 this.TypeAheadFactory.API.D(query)])
        .then(function (responses) {

    // to do
            dfd.resolve(results);
        });

    return dfd.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the request and response and work on that. There is a concept of interceptors in angularjs. More can be found here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Hope this helps.

Comment: how will it help cancelling calls?